# How to make classic search the default search experience with modern sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2019, classic-experience

I am setting up a new on-prem SharePoint 2019 farm. The goal is to use the modern experience for site collections since it is responsive and that is where Microsoft is putting future development into. However, with initial user testing, the modern search experience is abysmal and lacks several key features like: refiners, number or results found, custom display templates, etc.

I would like to continue to use modern sites, but have it default to use the classic search experience instead of the modern one. I have searched to see if there is a way to accomplish this but haven't come across anything. I was wondering if it is possible to do this? And if so, how do you do it?

I know that there is a more link at the bottom of the modern search results but to having to tell users to constantly click that link after doing your initial search is a horrible user experience - not to mention a waste of time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After filing a ticket with Microsoft regarding this question, the response was that (currently) this is not possible to accomplish.